# Do I have to install a old version of windows before installing the Windows 7 family pack upgrade?

Tags: windows-7, windows, installation

I am planning on getting the windows 7 family pack for I have 3 machine at home.
I notice it is an upgrade instead of a full version.
Is there any difference? I can't find one that doesn't label "Upgrade".

Also, I like to install OS from scratch. Never liked upgrading.
With the family pack, I can install from a machine with no OS installed?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, clean install is supported you'll just need to have your Vista DVD on hand during install to verify you're eligible to upgrade.

Comment: Does the installer need an actually DVD?  What if your copy of XP or Vista is OEM?  I'd think all you'd need would be a license key

Comment: From my past upgrade experience (XP -> Vista), yes a disk was required. I have yet to see an OEM ship Vista without including a copy of the DVD (although I'm no longer working in tech support) and while XP often shipped without disks (recovery partition, etc) that's irrelevant as upgrade is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

I have read up on this and it is possible to do an Windows 7 installation on a clean hard disk, it involves editing the registry...it was noted on lifehacker.com... alternatively google for "Windows 7 upgrade + clean install" (without quotes) and you should come across a few hits on it... it is apparently legal, to get windows 7 without having an older version of windows on it...the only thing that I can think of is, to have an existing key perhaps labelled on the back of the machine or case?

Answer (score 0):

If the three machines already have a Windows operating system installed, the upgrade CD can also do a clean installation.

If you're encountering any problems, read this Vista article for more details (probably the same for Win7):
[How to Clean Install Windows Vista with Upgrade Media](http://www.winsupersite.com/showcase/winvista_upgrade_clean.asp)